# Having problems with a formula involving Radon-Nykodym derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $T$ be a measurable function and $ T_{*} \mu << \mu$ (the pullback).  Suppose we can define locally a.e. $T^{-1}_{*} \mu$ and $ T^{-1}_{*} \mu << \mu$

Then,

$\displaystyle \sum_{T(y)=x} \frac{1}{\frac{dT^{-1}_{*} \mu}{d\mu}(y)} =  \frac{dT_{*} \mu}{d\mu}(x) $

I don't know how to deal with this and I tried to prove it by integrating both sides wrt $\mu$ and then use the fact that the Radon-Nikodym derivative is unique $\mu-$a.e.  (which actually do'esnt prove what I want since it is an equality for all x)

Thank you.

Comment: But you can at least prove this is one such Radon-Nikodym derivative.

Comment: I edited it because it was $T^{-1}_*\mu << \mu$

Comment: Use `\ll`. $ $ $ $

Comment: I don't get what you said

Comment: @Zhör: if you use `\ll` you get $\ll$ rather than $<<$ which does not look aesthetic

Comment: I know that $T_* \mu  =\mu \circ T^{-1}$, but what is meant when you talk about the local definition of $T^{-1}_*\mu$?